# VLCJ - Next item in playlist won't start after previous track finished

Tags: java, audio, vlcj

I am writing an audio player that uses VLCJ to handle audio output.

I am able to get audio to play, and I am able to jump to a different track while the current track is playing (using `next()` in the example below).

However, if I call `next()` after the current track finishes. It will load the track, but the track won't make any noise.

If I manually skip to another track (again, using `next()`) after that, it works.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.AudioMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class VLCJFinishedBug {

    String[] trackList = new String[] {
        "D:\\test\\1.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\2.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\3.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\4.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\5.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\6.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\7.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\8.mp3",
        "D:\\test\\9.mp3",
    };

    int trackIndex = 0;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static final String NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH = "stage\\lib\\vlc";

    public VLCJFinishedBug( ) {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath( RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH );
        mediaPlayer = (new AudioMediaPlayerComponent().getMediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            public void finished ( MediaPlayer player ) {
                next();
            }
        });
    }

    private void playTrack( String trackLocation ) {
        System.out.println ( "Playing track: " + trackLocation );
        mediaPlayer.playMedia( trackLocation );
    }

    private String nextTrackString() {
        trackIndex++;
        if ( trackIndex >= trackList.length ) {
            System.out.println( "Reach end of track list." );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }

        return ( trackList [ trackIndex ] );
    }

    public void start() {
        trackIndex = 0;
        playTrack ( trackList[ 0 ] );
    }

    public void next() {
        playTrack ( nextTrackString() );
    }

    public void goToNearEnd() {
        mediaPlayer.setPosition( .98f );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        VLCJFinishedBug player = new VLCJFinishedBug();

        JButton start = new JButton ( "Start" );
        start.addActionListener( e -> player.start() );

        JButton next = new JButton ( "Next" );
        next.addActionListener( e -> player.next() );

        JButton goToNearEnd = new JButton ( "Go To Near End" );
        goToNearEnd.addActionListener( e -> player.goToNearEnd() );

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.add( start );
        content.add( next );
        content.add( goToNearEnd );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "VLC Play Test" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setContentPane( content );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

How do I start playing a new track after the current track finishes?

Comment: It seems the issue is that I'm trying to start a new player while its still processing the old finish. If I have the listener's "finish()" launch a new thread and wait a second before calling next, it works. This is obviously a bad solution, but it tells me what's going wrong -- I need to set some sort of flag in finished() rather than calling next() directly.

Comment: for this sort of thing with vlcj you're supposed to use a MediaList rather than managing the playlist yourself.